# Maven in intelliJ fails to read artifact descriptor - Snapshot update is enabled

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Last week I my laptop was updated to Windows 10. Since that time intelliJ is throwing Maven related errors which I have been unable to resolve. All of my Maven plugins are highlighted in red with an error for: "Failed to read artifact descriptor for (dependency).". This is happening with every single plugin and dependency. I should also mention this is a cloned project that works for everyone else so the problem is not with the pom.

Here is a screenshot of my Maven settings: 
[image]

I've tried many options to resolve this including: 
1. Invalidate Caches / Restart
2. Re import Project 
3. Re import Maven Dependencies.
4. Deleting the intelliJ .iml and .idea folder. 
5. Doing a Maven clean install (will touch on this in a moment). 
6. Doing a git pull and re importing. 
7. Installing an external Maven (newest version), adding it to the environment variables and intelliJ.

Below is the error output from console when I attempt to run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=**** "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.1.2 clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for (redacted)
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 78, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building (redacted)SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.923s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 10 15:26:17 EST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

CMD Prompt attempt at a version / clean / clean install i get the below results:

```
C:\Users\(redacted)\(redacted)\(redacted)>mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for (redacted)-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 73, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building (redacted) 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.697 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-11T10:09:44-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

C:\Users\(redacted)\repos2\gpp-automated-testing>
```

Last of all when I run mvn clean -e for detailed errors I get the following errors:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: repo.maven.apache.org

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org
```

I tried to ping the host, I was unsure exactly which of these was the correct way to ping host so I tried them all.

```
C:\Users\(redacted)\repos2\(redacted)>ping http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
Ping request could not find host http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\(redacted)\repos2\(redacted)>ping http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
Ping request could not find host http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom. Please check the name and try again.
C:\Users\(redacted)\repos2\(redacted)>ping http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/
Ping request could not find host http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/. Please check the name and try again.
C:\Users\(redacted)\repos2\(redacted)>ping http://repo.maven.apache.org
Ping request could not find host http://repo.maven.apache.org. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: What happen when you open a CMD console and you do a `ping` command to the host: repo.maven.apache.org ... what happen in the colleagues computers? For me, it seems an IP routing problem ...

Comment: Please see ping result in the edited post.

Comment: I don't see the update...

Comment: Try to do the ping without the protocol part... I mean like this: `ping repo.maven.apache.org`

Comment: Same result, host can not be found.

Comment: It seems you have a DNS problem... are you behind a company firewall?

Comment: Yes I am, but my coworkers use the exact same pom & version of intelliJ. Still, I can't think of any other issue I just don't understand why it's only affecting me.

Comment: Another question: does your company have its own maven repository that all employees must point to?

Comment: No - we do not have our own Maven repository. We connect to the actual Maven.

Comment: Try to to do the ping command in one of your coworkers machine....

Comment: Okay, actually it appears that we do have a company repository. My coworker is pointing to the correct place and I am not, do you know where this setting is changed? The ping gave him the name of the actual repo.

Comment: @jesric1029, base on this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210983/10258377, how did you solve the problem? I face the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey ... you have a DNS problem... this means that the logical name: `repo.maven.apache.org` cannot be translated to an IP Address... this is  a problem of your operating system and your network administrator... so your pom and intellij are okey...

UPDATE: 
If your have a company repo, you need to add the company repo in your `.m2/settings.xml` file... in windows, that folder is located at your user system folder

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks for your help saved me some serious stress!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to bellow warnings

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective
model for (redacted) 
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 78, column 21 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is 
highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability 
of your build. [WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support 
building such malformed projects.
```

I would like to suggest you to use latest version of maven-compiler-plugin which is at present 3.7.0. Sorry I do not have solutions for rest of the problem.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I would avoid answers like this in the future, you aren't directly answering the question but instead just giving advice - others will certainly downvote you but I will not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have faced same warnings and therefore did the same and resolved the above warnings.